# simple python file search and record to csv

Tags: python, csv, os.walk

```
import os, csv


f=open("C:\\tempa\\file.csv", 'wb')  #write to an existing blank csv file
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files, in os.walk("C:\\tempa"):
    for filename in files:
        w.writerow([filename])
```

running win7 64bit  latest python, using `anaconda spyder`, `pyscripter` issue persists regardless of the ide.

I have some media in folders in **tempa**  **jpg**, **pdf** and **mov**... and I wanted to get a file list of all of them, and the code works but it stops without any issue at **row 113**, nothing special with the file it stops on, no weird characters.

I could have 3 blocks of code one for each folder to work around this weird bug. but it shouldnt have an issue.. the folders are all in the root folder without going too deep in sub folders:

```
C:\
-tempa
 -jpg
 -pdf
 -mov
```

I have heard there are issues with os.walk but I didn't expext anything weird like this.

Maybe I need an `f=close`?

Comment: What if you print the filenames instead of writing them to a csv file?

Comment: i need them in a csv file as im going to parse their filenames to work with merging on other csv files.. figured id use pandas for that.

Comment: thx for the formatting edit Bryan Posas....

Comment: solved my own issue.. it needed f.close()  now it grabs all the files without stopping... not sure why. but ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were examining the file before it was fully closed. (`f` won't be closed until, at least, it is no longer referenced by any in-scope variable name.) If you examine a file before it is closed, you may not see the final, partial, data buffer.

Use the `file` object's context manager to ensure that the file is flushed and closed in all cases:

```
import os, csv

with open("C:\\tempa\\file.csv", 'wb') as f:  #write to an existing blank csv file
    w=csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files, in os.walk("C:\\tempa"):
        for filename in files:
            w.writerow([filename])
    # Now no need for f.close()
```